# Social FrameWork not found in ios5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I added social framework in my project & make as a optional. My app is also not crash for ios5. 

`But when i try to open my project in xcode 4.2,It shows me error on #import<Social/Social.h>` like social.h not found.

So,i can't able to do any coding on old xcode version.

What can i do now?

Comment: you are not set Header path properly

Comment: Social Framework is available from iOS 6 not from iOS 5 so it will not work in ios 5. And xcode 4.2 dont have iOS 6 compatibility so it cannot find where Social framework coming from so it was showing error

Comment: @DixitPatel i am not set any Header Path for this framework because it is built-in framework in ios6.

Comment: @Sumanth, I know what you are saying, but how can i do coding by solve this issue.

Comment: remove the social framework from Xcode if you are developing project in xcode 4.2 and use third party library for implementing facebook and twitter instead of using social framework. Else develop your project in xcode 4.5 add social framework as optional and keep if condition for checking device is > ios6 if not use third party library for devices less than ios6

Comment: refer http://www.mobile.safilsunny.com/integrating-facebook-ios-6/

Comment: If you added the Social framework you must have used Xcode 4.5 to do so. Why are you now using Xcode 4.2? Stick with Xcode 4.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Social Framework is available from iOS 6 not from iOS 5 so it will not work in ios 5. Xcode 4.2 don't have iOS 6 compatibility, iOS6 is supported in xcode 4.5 or later so Xcode 4.2 cannot find where Social framework coming from so it was showing error

Answer (score 2):

Social Framework is available from iOS 6 not from iOS 5 so it will give error in ios 5. Xcode 4.2 don't have iOS 6 compatibility, iOS6 is supported in xcode 4.5 or later so Xcode 4.2 cannot find where Social framework and thus there is error.

You can also make the framework as "optional" not "required". You can do this changes by going to "Build Phases" -> "Link Binary With Libraries". And you have to check for framework class by coding.

Cheers!